# How do I create a C64 style loading screen in Java (Swing/SWT/AWT)?

Tags: java, swing, swt, awt

I was thinking of doing a [commodore 64 style loading screen](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GQYZ-YA9o2g) (with the alternating bars that change colour and grow/shrink in size) and was wondering if anyone has tried this or knows of any code I could look at. I'm gonna make a start on it myself today, but it would be good to have something to compare it against :)

So far, I'm guessing you divide the screen size up and set a constant for the bar height (say 12 horizontal bars for example) and you pick a random number between the constant and constant - 5 or whatever and refresh the screen. It's hard to tell looking at it, but it's something I'd be interested in reproducing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd override `paintComponent()` to draw the horizontal bars. To tile the overlay, you might look at this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078354) that uses `getSubimage()` to slice the image and `javax.swing.Timer` to pace the animation.

Addendum: See also this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605554/more-efficient-layout-than-box/6605702#6605702) that does horizontal slices.