# Dynamically add components without clicking button

Tags: java, swing, runtime, jcomponent

I am adding the components dynamically at runtime on clicking the button.
But now i want to add components Dynamically without clicking button.
How can i do that..?? Here is my source code for adding a component on clicking the Button.

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        String[] items = new String[4];
        items[0]="English";
        items[1]="French";
        items[2]="Spanish";
        items[3]="Hindi";
        JTextField jtextfield = new JTextField();
        jtextfield.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 20));
        JButton jbutton = new JButton();
        jbutton.setText("Remove");
        jbutton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(89, 23));

        JLabel jlabel = new JLabel();
        jlabel.setText("Text:");
        jlabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 20));
        JLabel jlabel2 = new JLabel();
        jlabel2.setText("Language:");
        jlabel2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(65, 20));

        JComboBox jcombo = new JComboBox();
        jcombo.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80,20));
        jcombo.addItem(items[0]);
        jcombo.addItem(items[1]);
        jcombo.addItem(items[2]);
        jcombo.addItem(items[3]);

        jPanel6.add(jlabel);
        jPanel6.add(jtextfield);
        jPanel6.add(jlabel2);
        jPanel6.add(jcombo);
        jPanel6.add(jbutton);

        jbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Component[]storeAllButtonInPanel = jPanel6.getComponents();

                if(storeAllButtonInPanel.length!=0) {
                    jPanel6.remove(storeAllButtonInPanel.length-1);
                    jPanel6.remove(storeAllButtonInPanel.length-2);
                    jPanel6.remove(storeAllButtonInPanel.length-3);
                    jPanel6.remove(storeAllButtonInPanel.length-4);
                    jPanel6.remove(storeAllButtonInPanel.length-5);

                    jPanel6.revalidate();
                    validate();
                    repaint();
                }
            }

        });



        jPanel6.validate();
        jPanel6.repaint();
    }
```

And if i have only 2 values of Text then it also disply two rows and if 3 values then there should be only 3 rows..!! How can i do that.?

Comment: You might want to write code in the "Constructor" method.

Comment: unrelated to your problem (just glaring at me in your example :) Do not use setXXSize (XX == min/pref/max) for reasons, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swing

Answer (score 2):

no idea what do you want, there is needed / required some control about that, as output to the GUI and by using some of [Listener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html) (as your [ActionListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)),

maybe (with full control) [JPopupMenu](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html), [API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JPopupMenu.html), examples [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/AnexampleoftheJPopupMenuinaction.htm) or [here](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing/Popup.html)

Answer (score 2):

An instance of [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) can periodically invoke the `actionPerformed()` method of an [`ActionListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html), as suggested in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605554/more-efficient-layout-than-box/6605702#6605702) that adds and removes `JLabel`s.

Comment: somebody has there, better idea +1