# Parsing Images Into Multiple Images

Tags: java, image, parsing

I'm making a game with custom text icons, I want to load each of the images from one Image. How can I split one Image into a bunch of other images that are just part of the original images?

Comment: Also consider `getSubimage()`, shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3078354/230513).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`CropImageFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/CropImageFilter.html)

> An ImageFilter class for cropping images. This class extends the basic ImageFilter Class to extract a given rectangular region of an existing Image and provide a source for a new image containing just the extracted region

You have to use it with [`FilteredImageSource`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/FilteredImageSource.html)

> This class is an implementation of the ImageProducer interface which takes an existing image and a filter object and uses them to produce image data for a new filtered version of the original image.

e.g.

```
public class Part extends JPanel {
    private Image src;

    public Part(Image src) {
        this.src = src;
    }

    public Image create(int xPos, int yPos, int width, int height) {
        ImageFilter cropImagefilter = new CropImageFilter(xPos, yPos, width, height); //see constructor detail
        FilteredImageSource filteredImageSource = new FilteredImageSource(this.src.getSource(), cropImagefilter)
        Image part = createImage(filteredImageSource);
        return part;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting this createImage function?

Comment: @blazingkin: You are welcome. It's here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#createImage%28java.awt.image.ImageProducer%29