# TextField is not getting updated when setText("...") is called?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtextfield

I am currently developing MineSweeper in java.In that I have to update JTextFields(as shown in Fig.) When I call setText(), Logger shows it is properly called. But in output there is no response.

[image]

My Actual code is as Below...

```
class GameInfoDisplayer{
          ...............
void setGameStatusText(String s){
    statusDisplayer.setStatus(s);
}
          ..............
 <....Definition of TimeController Inner class Comes here....>
    ..............
private class StatusDisplayer{
    JTextField displayField;
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("StatusDisplayer");
    StatusDisplayer(){
        displayField = new JTextField();
        gameInfoFieldsContainer.add(displayField);
    }
    void setStatus(String s){
            gameInfoFieldsContainer.remove(displayField);
            displayField.setText(s);        
            gameInfoFieldsContainer.add(displayField);
            gameInfoFieldsContainer.revalidate();
            gameInfoFieldsContainer.repaint();  
            logger.info("I am in updating Display content...:"+displayField.getText());
        }
    }
```

I did all  repainting, revalidating as given in [similar
    question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078178/jpanel-in-puzzle-game-not-updating) but there is no use..

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: It is difficult to tell the problem with the info available.  Many Swing problems with 'strange' behavior occur because updating is not done on the event dispatch thread; make sure you are using invokeAndWait or invokeLater as needed.

Comment: Are you calling `new StatusDisplayer()` or something of the sort before calling `setStatus()`? The textfield isn't actually defined until you call `new StatusDisplayer()`, so calling `setStatus()` first causes a NullPointerException.

Comment: @fireshadow52  I call  new StatusDisplayer() in the constructor of GameInfoDisplayer. (That was not shown here).

Comment: @EAGER_STUDENT *Before* calling `setGameStatusText()` I'm assuming?

Comment: Why would you remove and then add back the same component? All you need to do is invoke the setText() method (assuming you have a reference to the text field that is displayed on the GUI).

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
private class StatusDisplayer{
    JTextField displayField;
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("StatusDisplayer");
    StatusDisplayer(){
        displayField = new JTextField();
        gameInfoFieldsContainer.add(displayField);
    }
    void setStatus(String s){
            displayField.setText(s);        
            logger.info("I am in updating Display content...:"+displayField.getText());
        }
    }
}
```