# Selecting a part of Image while Cropping

Tags: java, image, swing

I'm cropping a image in java swing, but when I select a part of image for cropping, I need to make selection part visible to user. 
Like a transparent rectangle on that image.

Comment: In the future, please include a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) if you want any help.

Comment: So draw a rectangle on top of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`GraphPanel`](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/graphpanel) shows one approach to rendering such a selection rectangle, `mouseRect`. The rendering is controlled by the `boolean selecting` attribute.

Addendum: Once you know the bounds of the selection, you can use `getSubimage()` to clone the corresponding part of the image. There's a related example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3078354/230513).