# Java GUI Dynamic Repositioning of Objects

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

Hello StackOverflow users!

I have a problem and I did find a *solution* to the problem, but I feel that the solution is not *optimal*. I feel like I used brute force to achieve what I wanted to do and am wondering if there might be a better way to achieve what I want.

Essentially what I have is a Java GUI application using the GridBagLayout. I use the GridBagLayout because the layout is essentially always center-aligned. When something else is added in, it shifts everything up, down, left, or right (depending on where the new object is added in). The issue, is that my program also needs to remove certain objects (depending on what happens in other blocks of code). So lets say I have four objects lined up like this `[1] [2] [3] [4]` and I want to remove `[3]`. I essentially want the layout to change to `[1] [2] [3]`, essentially shifting everything over after the `[3]`. There was no problem doing this visually (because of how GridBagLayout works). However, when something new was to be added to the display, there would be overlap because though `[4]` took the visual position of `[3]`, the GridBagPosition (not sure what else to call it) did not change. So I implemented the code below for the removal process.

```
public void removeSubImagePanel (int subPanelIdx) {
    int x, y, nextX, nextY;
    this.remove(this.portraits[subPanelIdx]);

    nextX = this.portraits[subPanelIdx].getGbx();
    nextY = this.portraits[subPanelIdx].getGby();

    for (int i = subPanelIdx; i < this.numberOfPortraits; i++) {
        x = nextX;
        y = nextY;

        this.portraits[i] = this.portraits[i+1];
        if (this.portraits[i+1] != null) {
            nextX = this.portraits[i+1].getGbx();
            nextY = this.portraits[i+1].getGby();
            this.portraits[i].getObject().setSubPanelIdx(i);
            gbc.gridx = x;
            gbc.gridy = y;
            this.portraits[i].setGbLocation(x, y);
            gb.setConstraints(this.portraits[i], gbc);
        }
    }
    this.portraits[this.numberOfPortraits] = null;
    this.numberOfPortraits--;
}
```

Essentially, I added two integer variables to the "portraits" object to hold the position of the X and Y on the GridBagLayout. That way, I could get the position `[3]`, get the position of `[4]` set `[4]`s position to where `[3]`'s was and then (if there was a `[5]`, set `[5]`'s position to `[4]`'s old position and so on until I arrived at the last element.

It feels too "brute force", having to add those integers, and I feel like it would be even worse if I were to make an individual GridBagConstraint for each object. Is there a better way to do this shifting that I need to do?

Sorry, this question is quite long. I didn't think it would be so long. I hope this is still okay. If I was unclear and you need any clarification, please don't hesitate to ask!

Edit: Would it be better if this were on the CodeReview stackexchange? It actually seems to make more sense to have it there. I'm not quite sure though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078354) shows that it is possible to remove all components from a container and completely replace each component in arbitrary order. The time required to `validate()` the enclosing container is negligible, as the components themselves remain unchanged.

Comment: Hello! I took a look at the example and I kind of see how it might apply in the general scope of what I am asking (especially regarding what my title is saying!). But What I want to do is _keep_ the order, and only remove one thing. For example, `[1] [2] [3]` and I want to remove `[1]`. I want to shift `[2] and [3]` to become `[1] and [2]` (changing not only their visual location, but also the numbers in their 'gbc') Then, for some reason if I add the old `[1]` back, it will actually be the new `[3]` and be tacked on at the end of the "list".

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something that you have and maybe that's why you sent that link. If I misunderstood, please do tell me! I'm just having a hard time seeing how that link directly applies to my described situation. Though I do definitely see how that link applies to this question in a more _general_ sense!

Comment: Right, `Container` methods such as `removeAll()`, `add()` and `validate()` don't care what components or layout are used. If you `removeAll()` and `add()` `[2]` and `[3]`, they'll go in the slots previously occupied by `[1]` and `[2]`.

Comment: Hmm I see where you're going with that. But my question then is, if you `removeAll()` and then you add back `[2]` and `[3]`, will there be a _noticeable_ blink? Like a _refresh_ or something similar to that.

Comment: `JPanel` is double buffered by default. Try it and see!

Comment: Hmm I see. Thanks a lot! I don't know _100%_ if this is _better_ (more efficient) than adding two integers to each object, but it's definitely a good way of doing it! Is it very taxing (to the computer) to remove and re-add to layout?

Comment: It's a trade-off; only profiling will tell. For reference, `validate()` calls `doLayout()` to do similar arithmetic.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your requirements are for this project, but I would check out the [Spring Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/spring.html) - this layout lets you specify things like:

```
the left of [1] should be 10 pixels from the left of the panel
the right of [1]  should be 10 pixels from the left of [2]
etc.
```

It is much easier (imo) to implement a nice fluid layout like you are describing here.

**Edit:** Just to try and add to the discussion:

maybe you could have a class called PortraitPanel that extends from Panel and in there you could maintain a List of your image panels. You could have public methods:
    add(int index);
    remove(int index);

So that when you call add(2) it will add that panel to the list at that index - and then take the panel at index - 1 and index + 1 and do the routine to adjust the constraints on these so it lays them out on either side of the newly added panel. Similarly, for remove you could take index - 1 and set it's constraints to lay out next to index + 1 and then remove the item at index. Again, if you use a SpringLayout it will be really easy to set it up so that things remain fluid when the window resizes, etc.

Hopefully this is in line with what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer. I took a brief glance at Spring Layout and it seems really interesting! I'll keep that in mind for possible future projects, but I don't feel that it fits very well for this particular one. I believe that using the Spring Layout would complicate things. Say I had `[1] [2] [3] [4]` and wanted to remove `[2]`. It seems that I'd then have to change both `[1] and [3]` Also, I create a new row for every 4. so what if I had `[5] [6]` underneath `[1] [2]` and wanted to remove `[5]`? Then I'd need to change `[1] [2] and [6]` (Or to the very least that's my understanding.)