# Java gridlayout ignores gaps

Tags: java, swing, layout, grid-layout

I'm working on a checkers board in java.
But I have a strange problem:
Eventough I set the vgap at 0 it still creates a vgap.
There is a space of aprox 5px between the squares in height.
The width is alright.
This is my layout code of the Diagram object:

```
this.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 10, 0, 0));
this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(230, 230));
```

And this is where I implement the Diagram:

```
// The jpanel that has to contain the diagram
jpanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
add(jpanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
// The placement of the diagram in that jpanel
jp.add(new diagram());
```

This is how it looks:

```
[][][][][][][][][]
<The spacing that I have to get removed>
[][][][][][][][][]
```

But it should be like:

```
[][][][][][][][][]
[][][][][][][][][]

^
|
no spacing between them
```

Comment: My guess is whatever you put in the container that is put in each grid cell is not high enough. Please post a full example which reproduces your problem

Comment: I found the reason of the problem its the image inside the JLabel thats not shown for 100% height but less. How do I modify the height of an imageIcon?

Answer (score 3):

- you have to change `LayoutManager` for JPanel from [FlowLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html) to the [BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) or ...,
- `FlowLayout` pretty accepting `PreferredSize` came from layed JCompoments into container (`JPanel`), everything depends of

  1. `Diagram` returns `PreferredSize`
  2. if and how could be resizable `Diagram` with container
  3. how and where is really used [GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html)
- for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Could be `JPanel` UI delegate, too; no problem using `new JLabel(new ImageIcon())`, seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3078354/230513).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by loading the image into the JPanel instead of a JLabel
I made the image into a BufferedImage
then draw it onto the JPanel with drawImage