# Lining up components in a grid with grid-based background

Tags: java, swing, miglayout

[image]

I'm working on a college project and I'm having difficulty lining up components with the board grid. The board will always maintain a 1:1 width to height ratio but the size can vary. Here is what I've tried which resulted in this:

[image]

Why are the percentages not lining up with what I calculated them to be for the actual image size of 1200x1200?

Here's my layout code:

```
public class BoardPanel extends ViewComponent {

    public static final int ROWS = 27;
    public static final int COLS = 23;
    private Board board = new Board();

    private BufferedImage background = ResourceLoader.openImage("images/board.jpg");

    public BoardPanel() {
        this.add(board, "pos 4.5% 4.5%, width 76.5%, height 91%");           
    }

    @Override
    public void paintContent(Graphics2D g) {
        g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, getHeight(), getHeight(), null);
    }

    private class Board extends ViewComponent {

        public Board() {
            setLayout(new GridLayout(ROWS, COLS,  1, 1));

            for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++)
                for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++)
                    this.add(new Location(row, col));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know what layout ViewComponent uses, but 76.5 + 4.5 + 4.5 != 100 so you probably not using are the entire width (should be 91% like the height?)

Comment: It uses MigLayout as was tagged. And no because there are more rows than columns and the other squares don't count (the slightly larger ones).

Comment: Could you provide the `Location` and `ViewComponent` code ?

Comment: @gontard They are glorified `JComponents`, so replace `paintContent` with `paintComponent` and replace `ViewComponent` with `JComponent`. `paintContent` simply takes a `Graphics2D` instance with `RenderingHints` set to enable AA etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured out how to do this, and the answer comes when you look at the difference between **`GridLayout`** and **`MigLayout`**.

What happened was I had empty space (insets) when I used **`GridLayout`** because it forces all cells to be the same size. I noticed this when I added a 1px `LineBorder`.

The way **`MigLayout`** handles extra space is it seems to distribute the extra pixels among the cells, thereby forcing it to fix the container as ideally as possible. For example:

```
this.setLayout(new MigLayout("ins 0, wrap " + COLS + ", gap 1", "grow", "grow"));


        for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++)
            for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++)
                this.add(new Location(row, col), "grow");
```

[image]

Which uses the exact same container and panel size as the grid layout shown here:
(notice the insets)

```
this.setLayout(new GridLayout(ROWS, COLS, 1, 1));
this.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED));


    for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++)
        for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++)
            this.add(new Location(row, col));
```

[image]

Comment: I suggest it was Mr. Android in the kitchen with a compiler. :-)

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, use [`BufferedImage#getSubimage()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getSubimage%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) to divide the image into congruent pieces, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078354).

Comment: This is quite a good idea instead of forcing a 1px gap between each cell. I'll give it a shot and report back.

Comment: The example uses a zero gap `GridLayout`; resize the frame to see the effect of a larger gap.

Comment: +1 for the idea, though I'm liking the overlay-ness of what I've got going. :)