# Split image into clickable regions

Tags: java, image, swing, jlabel, java-2d

Is there any way to split an image to region (right now it's JLabel but I can change it if necessary)?
I use swing in my program and I have an image (square for this example) with some triangles, stars and trapezoids inside it (it can be JPG, PNG, etc).
The idea is that the user will click inside one of those shapes and then I will put another small icon on top of the area the user clicked. The user can click on multiple areas but at the end of the day, I need to know which shapes were clicked.

Seems possible anyone?

Comment: Do you already know how to divide the big image up into sprites (with each separate shape)?  If so, it should be fairly easy.  Just use the sub-images as icons for a `GridLayout` of toggle buttons.  So the answer is 'yes, it seems possible'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at what I have made:

This is the image I used for testing:

[image: Original Image]

After image has been split:

[image: After Image splitting]

And here is the source:

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JLabel[] labels;
    private static String imagePath = "c:/test.jpg";
    private final int rows = 3; //You should decide the values for rows and cols variables
    private final int cols = 3;
    private final int chunks = rows * cols;
    private final int SPACING = 10;//spacing between split images

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test().createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private void createAndShowUI() {
        frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        initComponents();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        BufferedImage[] imgs = getImages();

        //set contentpane layout for grid
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(rows, cols, SPACING, SPACING));

        labels = new JLabel[imgs.length];

        //create JLabels with split images and add to frame contentPane
        for (int i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
            labels[i] = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(imgs[i].getSource())));
            frame.getContentPane().add(labels[i]);
        }
    }

    private BufferedImage[] getImages() {
        File file = new File(imagePath); // I have bear.jpg in my working directory
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        BufferedImage image = null;
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(fis); //reading the image file
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        int chunkWidth = image.getWidth() / cols; // determines the chunk width and height
        int chunkHeight = image.getHeight() / rows;
        int count = 0;
        BufferedImage imgs[] = new BufferedImage[chunks]; //Image array to hold image chunks
        for (int x = 0; x < rows; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < cols; y++) {
                //Initialize the image array with image chunks
                imgs[count] = new BufferedImage(chunkWidth, chunkHeight, image.getType());

                // draws the image chunk
                Graphics2D gr = imgs[count++].createGraphics();
                gr.drawImage(image, 0, 0, chunkWidth, chunkHeight, chunkWidth * y, chunkHeight * x, chunkWidth * y + chunkWidth, chunkHeight * x + chunkHeight, null);
                gr.dispose();
            }
        }
        return imgs;
    }
}
```

The only flaw is I haven't checked if the image is larger then the screen which could cause problems, that would be resolved by a simple image resize using `getScaledInstance(int x,int y, int width, in height)` on the image and the separating it into chunks.

### Update

Sorry I missed the part if the question in Shapes, have a look at [`draw(Shape s)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#draw%28java.awt.Shape%29) method of `Graphics2D`/`Graphics`.

I read this:

> Any Shape object can be used as a clipping path that restricts the
>   portion of the drawing area that will be rendered. The clipping path
>   is part of the `Graphics2D` context; to set the clip attribute, you call
>   `Graphics2D.setClip` and pass in the Shape that defines the clipping
>   path you want to use.

See here for clipping an u]image to a shape: [Clipping the Drawing Region](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/clipping.html)

**References:**

- [How to Split an Image into Chunks - Java ImageIO](http://kalanir.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-to-split-image-into-chunks-java.html)

Comment: where should I change it, so theres no gap between those images?, sorry noob question

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `getSubImage()` method of `BufferedImage`, illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3078354/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/230513). The example also uses `JLabel`, but you can add the `Icon` to a `JButton` that can be clicked. There are several ways for a button to remember details about it's icon:

- Subclass `JButton` and add a suitable field.
- Add a client property to the parent `JComponent`.
- Use the `name` property of the parent `Component`.