# creating a clickable button of an image

Tags: java, image, swing, jbutton

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add a complex image in the panel, with buttons around it in one customized user interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10861852/add-a-complex-image-in-the-panel-with-buttons-around-it-in-one-customized-user)

I am creating an application which takes an image and imposes grid like look on the image (refer to [Split image into clickable regions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12418618/split-image-into-clickable-regions))

Now my question is how to make this image(after grid has been imposed) clickable.

[in other words the individual sub-parts of the image after applying grid have to be made CLICKABLE BUTTONS].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not clear what you mean by "Clickable Buttons"

If you want to have real buttons with images inside, then instead of `JLabel` create `JButton`:

```
buttons[i] = new JButton(new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(imgs[i].getSource())));
frame.getContentPane().add(labels[i]);
```

and then add `ActionListener` overriding `actionPerformed()`

If you want it to be labels, but clickable then add `MouseListener` to each `JLabel` overriding `mousePressed` or `mouseClicked` depending on desired behavior.

Comment: Buttons can be 'plain'.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/418556) for an example.

Comment: thanks NIKOLAY..but can you specify more on that...ypu know i'm not a PRO on that stuffs...thanks again...!!!

Comment: @user1967018, this website is for asking and answering specific questions with showing your effort and issues you are facing.

Comment: Just noticed.  `frame.getContentPane().add(labels[i]);`  If the frame uses default layout, only the first (or last - I forget) of those components will appear.  +1 for your answer, BTW.

Comment: *"i didnt get you"*  I would have said.  "Show some effort and we might help more."  Do you understand that?

Comment: got you...n again thanks,soon i'll be back with more on that..!!

Comment: @user1967018, welcome. In next question specify what exactly you are trying to achieve and your current related code. You might want to accept the answer with a green tick.

Comment: thanks to all..that has worked.
but the button image needs to be stretched to the entire area/span of the button 
AND,AND needs to be highlighted every time the mouse pointer is hovered upon the buttons.
is it possible?