# Flickering while revalidating JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jlabel

I have looked all round, and no one seems to have an answer for me. I have a `JPanel` where I add/remove labels from it while it;s running. The problem is that every time I add a new label to it I have to `revalidate()` it so the new label shows up. Every time I `revalidate()`, it I get a very annoying flicker, and all my labels ghost up to the top of my window for a millisecond then return to what they were doing. The only time I call `revalidate()` is after I add a label; I do not change the paint method or anything only did

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics page)
{
    super.paintComponent(page);
}
```

so that my page would not look bad. I could really use some help on this. I've made a asteroids game using `JFrame`, `Jlabel` and `Jpanel` game; it work great, but this flickering and component "ghosting quickly ghosting to top of panel" is just unbearable, and I know for a fact this is the `revalidate()` method.

Comment: for information, i have a label that represents a ship, bullets, and asteroids, i add and remove them to my panel as they are used shot or run out of life. using the add(component); and remove(conponent); then after i add i revalidate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using labels (or generally GUI components) to represent quickly animating, dynamically created/moved objects is not practical. Its like using a car to drive from the living room to the kitchen.

The Swing components come with a lot of nice features, e.g. they can determine the space they require and a layout manager can use that to automatically place them nicely. Unfortunately for a game, you neither need all the nice stuff, nor do you want to pay the processing overhead involved with it. Matters are further complicated by swings multi-platform capabilities which mandate that each component has a peer component (the peer deals with rendering the component to the active look).

To solve this, you do not represent individual game objects as swing components. Instead you use a single swing component (usually JPanel) as a canvas to paint your game objects on to. You simply call repaint() for that JPanel periodically (e.g. 30 or 60 times a second). Of course you will override paintComponent() on the JPanel to do paint all the game objects using your own code.

Edit: To outline how you do your own rendering

You need to decide how to organize your game related objects. A very simple skeleton could look like this (getters/setters omitted):

```
public class GameObject {
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public Image image;
}
```

In practice this class will have additional members (like a behavior that controls how the object moves, and maybe some states/counters for animation). It may also be abstract with a concrete subclass for each possible behavior (like ship, asteroid and bullet). All instances of GameObject are managed in some kind of collection, I assume you use a List.

When implementing the paintComponent it comes down to just loop through the list and render each objects's image:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    List<GameObject> list = ... // however you obtain it in your game
    for (GameObject gobject : list) {
        g.drawImage(gobject.image, gobject.x, gobject.y, (ImageObserver) null);
    }
}
```

More elaborate games may order the gameobjects to get control of how game objects overlap each other. But in principle its incredibly simple.

Comment: the only problem which i dont know how to get around because im a noob is that each thing i.e bullet, asteroid and ship, there are a good amount of things i dont know how to represent as graphics.

Comment: @Elton I added some brief description how you create your own game objects and render them

Answer (score 2):

When I was having problems with filckering Swing components it turned out to be concurrency issues. Since you are doing a game, which means you are doing animation it may be the case here.

Take care to modify Swing components only from `AWT-EVENT thread`. Either use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` or do your animation using `javax.swing.Timer`.

Answer (score 2):

As a concrete example, [`Asteroids`](http://rabbitbrush.frazmtn.com/asteroids.html) doesn't flicker at all. Here are a few reasons:

- It runs on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).
- It uses `JPanel`, which is double buffered by default.
- It paces the animation using `javax.swing.Timer`, updating the game's model in `actionPerformed()`.
- It overrides `paintComponent()`, but can safely omit `super.paintComponent()` because the action listener repaints the entire panel.
- The listener calls `paintImmediately()` to avoid any potential delay; substitute `repaint()` to see if there's any difference on your platform.

Addendum: As shown in this [counter-example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3078354/230513), `revalidate()` does not cause flickering. Instead of *replacing* labels, *update* the label's icon, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12228640/230513).

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered reusing them - i.e. using `setVisible(false)` when they're not needed?

Not sure if adding and removing labels is the best way of achieving what you want for a game. 
I'd personally be tempted to manage the drawing myself.

Comment: i think im going to try this, i am still amateur coder so this seems simplest to me, thanks for the feed back guys.