# Shuffling the images

Tags: java, swing, random, shuffle

I've made a picture puzzle game. actually I use Netbeans 8.2 GUI Builder to create the game, I have made `Timer` and move.

But I am confused how to shuffle the images. I've searched on various sites but it did not help.

This is my code:

```
package projetu;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import static projetu.fasil.cont;

public class t02 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    static int cont = 0;
    int i = 0;
    private Timer timer;
    private int currentSegundo = 0;
    private int currentMinuto = 0;
    private int currentHora = 0;
    private int velocidade = 1000;

    public t02() {
        initComponents();
        b9.setVisible(false);
    }

    public void contamuda() {
        txtconta.setText(String.valueOf(cont++));
    }

    private void iniciarContagem() {
        ActionListener action;
        action = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                currentSegundo++;

                if (currentSegundo == 60) {
                    currentMinuto++;
                    currentSegundo = 0;
                }

                if (currentMinuto == 60) {
                    currentHora++;
                    currentMinuto = 0;
                }

                String hr = currentHora <= 9 ? "0" + currentHora : currentHora + "";
                String min = currentMinuto <= 9 ? "0" + currentMinuto : currentMinuto + "";
                String seg = currentSegundo <= 9 ? "0" + currentSegundo : currentSegundo + "";

                tempu.setText(hr + ":" + min + ":" + seg);
            }
        };
        this.timer = new Timer(velocidade, action);
        this.timer.start();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        b1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        b2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        b3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        b4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        b5 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        b6 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        b7 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        b8 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        b9 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        txtconta = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        tempu = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel1.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(3, 3));

        b1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/tais/t11.gif"))); // NOI18N
        b1.setBorder(null);
        b1.setBorderPainted(false);
        b1.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        b1.setFocusable(false);
        b1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                b1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel1.add(b1);

        b2.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/tais/t12.gif"))); // NOI18N
        b2.setBorder(null);
        b2.setBorderPainted(false);
        b2.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        b2.setFocusable(false);
        b2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                b2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel1.add(b2);

        b3.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/tais/t13.gif"))); // NOI18N
        b3.setBorder(null);
        b3.setBorderPainted(false);
        b3.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        b3.setFocusable(false);
        b3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                b3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel1.add(b3);

        b4.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/tais/t14.gif"))); // NOI18N
        b4.setBorder(null);
        b4.setBorderPainted(false);
        b4.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        b4.setFocusable(false);
        b4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                b4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel1.add(b4);

        b5.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/tais/t15.gif"))); // NOI18N
        b5.setBorder(null);
        b5.setBorderPainted(false);
        b5.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        b5.setFocusable(false);
        b5.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                b5ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel1.add(b5);

        b6.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/tais/t16.gif"))); // NOI18N
        b6.setBorder(null);
        b6.setBorderPainted(false);
        b6.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        b6.setFocusable(false);
        b6.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                b6ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel1.add(b6);

        b7.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/tais/t17.gif"))); // NOI18N
        b7.setBorder(null);
        b7.setBorderPainted(false);
        b7.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        b7.setFocusable(false);
        b7.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                b7ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel1.add(b7);

        b8.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/tais/t18.gif"))); // NOI18N
        b8.setBorder(null);
        b8.setBorderPainted(false);
        b8.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        b8.setFocusable(false);
        b8.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                b8ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel1.add(b8);

        b9.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/tais/t19.gif"))); // NOI18N
        b9.setBorder(null);
        b9.setBorderPainted(false);
        b9.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        b9.setFocusable(false);
        b9.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                b9ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel1.add(b9);

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Trebuchet MS", 1, 36)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("Muda :");

        txtconta.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Trebuchet MS", 1, 36)); // NOI18N
        txtconta.setText("0");

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Trebuchet MS", 1, 36)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setText("Tempu =");

        tempu.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Trebuchet MS", 1, 36)); // NOI18N
        tempu.setText("00:00:00");

        jLabel3.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/tais01/t02_lbl.jpg"))); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setAutoscrolls(true);
        jLabel3.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder.RAISED));
        jLabel3.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                .addGap(0, 89, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        jButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Trebuchet MS", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jButton1.setText("Komesa");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Trebuchet MS", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jButton3.setText("Valor");

        jButton4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Trebuchet MS", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jButton4.setText("Sai ");
        jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Trebuchet MS", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jButton2.setText("Hili Imagen");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel3);
        jPanel3.setLayout(jPanel3Layout);
        jPanel3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton2)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton3)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton4)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Trebuchet MS", 1, 36)); // NOI18N
        jLabel4.setText("Game puzzle tais no uma adat iha Timor Leste");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 122, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(txtconta, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 85, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGap(52, 52, 52)
                                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                .addComponent(tempu))
                            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 639, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 56, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 413, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 52, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(txtconta, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(tempu, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void b1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        contamuda();
        if (b2.isVisible() == false) {
            b2.setText(b1.getText());
            b2.setIcon(b1.getIcon());
            b1.setVisible(false);
            b2.setVisible(true);
        }
        if (b4.isVisible() == false) {
            b4.setText(b1.getText());
            b4.setIcon(b1.getIcon());
            b1.setVisible(false);
            b4.setVisible(true);
        }
    }                                  

    private void b2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        contamuda();
        if (b1.isVisible() == false) {
            b1.setText(b2.getText());
            b1.setIcon(b2.getIcon());
            b2.setVisible(false);
            b1.setVisible(true);
        }
        if (b3.isVisible() == false) {
            b3.setText(b2.getText());
            b3.setIcon(b2.getIcon());
            b2.setVisible(false);
            b3.setVisible(true);
        }
        if (b5.isVisible() == false) {
            b5.setText(b2.getText());
            b5.setIcon(b2.getIcon());
            b2.setVisible(false);
            b5.setVisible(true);
        }
    }                                  

    private void b3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        contamuda();
        if (b2.isVisible() == false) {
            b2.setText(b3.getText());
            b2.setIcon(b3.getIcon());
            b3.setVisible(false);
            b2.setVisible(true);
        }
        if (b6.isVisible() == false) {
            b6.setText(b3.getText());
            b6.setIcon(b3.getIcon());
            b3.setVisible(false);
            b6.setVisible(true);
        }
    }                                  

    private void b4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        contamuda();
        if (b1.isVisible() == false) {
            b1.setText(b4.getText());
            b1.setIcon(b4.getIcon());
            b4.setVisible(false);
            b1.setVisible(true);
        }
        if (b5.isVisible() == false) {
            b5.setText(b4.getText());
            b5.setIcon(b4.getIcon());
            b4.setVisible(false);
            b5.setVisible(true);
        }
        if (b7.isVisible() == false) {
            b7.setText(b4.getText());
            b7.setIcon(b4.getIcon());
            b4.setVisible(false);
            b7.setVisible(true);
        }
    }                                  

    private void b5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        contamuda();
        if (b2.isVisible() == false) {
            b2.setText(b5.getText());
            b2.setIcon(b5.getIcon());
            b5.setVisible(false);
            b2.setVisible(true);
        }
        if (b4.isVisible() == false) {
            b4.setText(b4.getText());
            b4.setIcon(b4.getIcon());
            b5.setVisible(false);
            b4.setVisible(true);
        }
        if (b6.isVisible() == false) {
            b6.setText(b5.getText());
            b6.setIcon(b5.getIcon());
            b5.setVisible(false);
            b6.setVisible(true);
        }
        if (b8.isVisible() == false) {
            b8.setText(b5.getText());
            b8.setIcon(b5.getIcon());
            b5.setVisible(false);
            b8.setVisible(true);
        }
    }                                  

    private void b6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        contamuda();
        if (b9.isVisible() == false) {
            b9.setText(b6.getText());
            b9.setIcon(b6.getIcon());
            b6.setVisible(false);
            b9.setVisible(true);
        }
        if (b3.isVisible() == false) {
            b3.setText(b6.getText());
            b3.setIcon(b6.getIcon());
            b6.setVisible(false);
            b3.setVisible(true);
        }
        if (b5.isVisible() == false) {
            b5.setText(b6.getText());
            b5.setIcon(b6.getIcon());
            b6.setVisible(false);
            b5.setVisible(true);
        }
    }                                  

    private void b7ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        contamuda();
        if (b4.isVisible() == false) {
            b4.setText(b7.getText());
            b4.setIcon(b7.getIcon());
            b7.setVisible(false);
            b4.setVisible(true);
        }
        if (b8.isVisible() == false) {
            b8.setText(b7.getText());
            b8.setIcon(b7.getIcon());
            b7.setVisible(false);
            b8.setVisible(true);
        }
    }                                  

    private void b8ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        contamuda();
        if (b5.isVisible() == false) {
            b5.setText(b8.getText());
            b5.setIcon(b8.getIcon());
            b8.setVisible(false);
            b5.setVisible(true);
        }
        if (b7.isVisible() == false) {
            b7.setText(b7.getText());
            b7.setIcon(b7.getIcon());
            b8.setVisible(false);
            b7.setVisible(true);
        }
        if (b9.isVisible() == false) {
            b9.setText(b8.getText());
            b9.setIcon(b8.getIcon());
            b8.setVisible(false);
            b9.setVisible(true);
        }
    }                                  

    private void b9ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        contamuda();
        if (b6.isVisible() == false) {
            b6.setText(b9.getText());
            b6.setIcon(b9.getIcon());
            b9.setVisible(false);
            b6.setVisible(true);
        }
        if (b8.isVisible() == false) {
            b8.setText(b9.getText());
            b8.setIcon(b9.getIcon());
            b9.setVisible(false);
            b8.setVisible(true);
        }
    }                                  

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        iniciarContagem();
    }                                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        new hili_imagen().setVisible(true);
        dispose();
    }                                        

    private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        new game().setVisible(true);
        dispose();
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(t02.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(t02.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(t02.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(t02.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new t02().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton b1;
    private javax.swing.JButton b2;
    private javax.swing.JButton b3;
    private javax.swing.JButton b4;
    private javax.swing.JButton b5;
    private javax.swing.JButton b6;
    private javax.swing.JButton b7;
    private javax.swing.JButton b8;
    private javax.swing.JButton b9;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel tempu;
    private javax.swing.JLabel txtconta;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: One of the simplest ways to shuffle anything is to use [`Collections.shuffle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-)

Comment: *"shuffling the images **using Netbeans 8.2 IDE**"* The answer is to be found in Java, not the IDE used to develop it.

Comment: Most of the code you have posted seems irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3078354/230513).

Comment: Please post a [mcve], with an emphasis on "Minimal".